# How do I bake in a photo's Auto Enhance adjustments?

Tags: ios, photos, photos.app

The Auto Enhance feature in iOS Photos often leads to results I like. But when I go to share those photos, or to edit them in Lightroom, etc. the adjustments are stripped out.

I want to bake the results of the Auto Enhance AI magic into an image that I can then share or edit elsewhere.

I'm finding no documentation for the feature, and most of what I discover across the web describes the process for turning the feature off.

Last thing: Even taking a screenshot of an auto enhanced image doesn't capture its adjustments. The resulting screenshot is just the bland version I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to export the image to the file system and then import it back in as a separate image. Photos.app may consider it a duplicate.